# Python gtk with box and Entry()

Tags: python, gtk, pygtk

I an new to gtk but not at all to python, I am trying to create a box on my window and then put the entry function within gtk. This is the way I thought I should do it. My goal is to have a spot on my gtk window that excepts keyboard input, however in my research I can not seem to find a way that works.

My code:

```
try:
    import gtk, os, sys
except:
    print("Install Packages First")
    exit()

class clamav:
    def textbox(self, widget):
        self.window.set_title("Current Change")
        print("Channel Working")    

    def install(self, widget):
        os.system('python AntiViroid.py -i')
        sys.exit()

    def update(self, widget):
        os.system('python AntiViroid.py -u')
        sys.exit()  

    def exitwin(self, widget):
        sys.exit()
        #os.system('exit')

    def __init__(self):
        #Make Window:
        self.window = gtk.Window(gtk.WINDOW_TOPLEVEL)
        self.window.set_default_size(250, 200)
        self.window.modify_bg(gtk.STATE_NORMAL, gtk.gdk.color_parse("gray"))
        self.window.connect("destroy", lambda w :gtk.main_quit())

        #Make Button Alignment:
        self.fixed = gtk.Fixed()
            self.window.add(self.fixed)
            self.fixed.show()

        #Make C_Dialog
        box = gtk.HBox()
        entry = gtk.Entry()
        box.pack_start(box)
        self.fixed.put(box, 40, 40)


        #Button_Listings:
        self.button1 = gtk.Button("Install")
        self.fixed.put(self.button1, 0, 0)
        self.button1.connect("clicked", self.install)

        self.button2 = gtk.Button("Update")
        self.fixed.put(self.button2, 55, 0)
        self.button2.connect("clicked", self.update)

        self.button3 = gtk.Button("Kill and Quit")
        self.fixed.put(self.button3, 250, 200)
        self.button3.connect("clicked", self.exitwin)

        self.button1.show()
        self.button2.show()
        self.button3.show()
        self.window.show()


    def main(self):
            gtk.main()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    clamav = clamav()
    clamav.main()
```

This right here is the problem:

```
box = gtk.HBox()
entry = gtk.Entry()
box.pack_start(box)
self.fixed.put(box, 40, 40)
```

In running this I get:

ViroidGUI.py:39: GtkWarning: IA__gtk_widget_set_parent: assertion 'widget != parent' failed
  box.pack_start(box)
Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Comment: `box.pack_start(box)` adds the box to itself, which you can't do. Did you accidentally make a typo?

Comment: Also pygtk is dead you should move to pygobject.